# Entity Framework (MVC) - Problem with creating controller for Model that has protected properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework. I have a public model class that has protected access modifier on properties which have private set access modifier.
Is it possible to create a controller for model that has protected properties with private set?

Model class:

```
public class Movie
{
    protected int ID { get; private set; }
    protected string Title { get; private set; }
    protected DateTime ReleaseDate { get; private set; }
    protected string Genre { get; private set; }
    protected decimal Price { get; private set; }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I try to create that kind of a controller I get an error:
[image]

I have tried to add `[key]` prefix before ID property but that didn't help.

Comment: Your primary key needs to be `public` access modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary key needs to be `public` access modifier.

```
 public class Movie
 {
     public int ID { get; private set; }
 }
```